# Use PHP to open log file and find IP adresses in that file

Tags: php

I have a log file that has IP adresses in it mixed with text. I need to extract all IP adresses from that log file and present it in a table. I am struggeling with the IP extraction part. I think this line is giving me bad results:

```
$check_for_ip = preg_replace('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', "", $line);
```

log.txt

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 192.130.20.10 sit amet, 120.130.140.150 consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel congue diam. Sed lobortis tristique felis. Nulla facilisi. Aenean sit amet posuere felis. Donec laoreet, neque et scelerisque interdum, tortor urna pulvinar odio, a placerat est mi ut lorem. Nunc massa velit, congue in blandit quis, dapibus at dui. Morbi gravida et quam id ultricies. Suspendisse magna lorem, placerat at semper vel, vehicula vel arcu. Nam suscipit fermentum turpis vel maximus. Sed vitae mauris dolor. Proin congue urna eu odio accumsan, nec tempus massa venenatis. Nam malesuada ligula nec bibendum imperdiet. Sed bibendum, massa et auctor convallis, nibh dui dictum nisl, eu posuere orci magna sed ipsum. Nullam suscipit luctus vulputate.
Vivamus hendrerit 127.1.1.0 justo eu 6.7.8.9 dignissim eleifend. Donec laoreet ligula at vehicula sodales. Donec a lectus est. Phasellus auctor massa non nisl commodo accumsan. Integer nisl augue, rhoncus in dapibus nec, bibendum vel libero. Etiam nibh arcu, eleifend et erat non, finibus commodo ipsum. Quisque lobortis egestas arcu quis suscipit. Nam tempus turpis eu sodales fringilla. Praesent ac justo pellentesque, egestas eros quis, pharetra enim. Nam nunc tortor, fermentum in fringilla sit amet, sodales vitae neque. Cras ullamcorper sed tortor in faucibus. Mauris condimentum ligula vitae eros tristique convallis in ultricies urna. In diam orci, feugiat et eleifend a, pellentesque ac quam. Pellentesque non urna nulla.
Aenean mattis varius risus. Praesent tellus augue, rhoncus eget augue a, luctus elementum augue. Vestibulum finibus egestas diam, eget porttitor turpis tincidunt sit amet. Nullam semper nisi magna, vel consequat massa congue ut. Nulla orci nisi, euismod et accumsan ac, dapibus eget est. In accumsan enim sed diam semper, eget tincidunt nunc ornare. Praesent id tristique massa. In volutpat aliquet porta. Aenean vitae risus nec ex mollis finibus. Quisque ut sodales nisl. Pellentesque bibendum blandit mauris a tincidunt. Morbi sodales ante ut elit pharetra, a auctor sapien faucibus.
Donec vestibulum, sem non convallis congue, magna elit consequat velit, eu aliquam libero arcu vitae sem. Etiam eu viverra arcu, ut gravida massa. Vivamus mollis feugiat magna, ac feugiat ipsum. Praesent rhoncus est sed ligula semper, in interdum metus suscipit. Praesent fermentum mauris ac mauris cursus, non dapibus leo egestas. Suspendisse venenatis purus quis condimentum venenatis. Donec at turpis eget augue placerat tempor porta convallis purus. Integer hendrerit tincidunt velit sit amet accumsan. Quisque iaculis eu odio vel commodo. Aenean sit amet dapibus turpis, ultricies pulvinar nulla.
Vestibulum semper quam eget magna semper tempus. Ut tempor ligula nisi, non mattis leo lobortis ac. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed auctor eros felis, a ultrices nisi sagittis id. Vestibulum id dapibus est. Morbi elementum metus ipsum, eget suscipit turpis convallis et. Suspendisse pellentesque risus non pharetra tempus. Proin pulvinar sed lorem tincidunt posuere. Ut vehicula condimentum convallis. Integer tortor orci, fermentum nec ultrices nec, efficitur sed nisl.
```

Script:

```
<?php


// Find IPs
$fh = fopen("log.txt", "r");
$data = fread($fh, filesize("log.txt"));
fclose($fh); 

$array = explode("\n", $data);
$array_size = sizeof($array);

$ip_array = array();

for($x=0;$x<$array_size;$x++){
    $line = $array[$x];
    $check_for_ip = preg_replace('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', "", $line);

    // Check if IP already exists
    if (!(in_array($check_for_ip, $ip_array))) {
        array_push($ip_array, $check_for_ip);
    }
}


// Print result
echo"
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <p><b>ID</b></p>
   </th>
   <th>
    <p><b>IP</b></p>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>";
for($x=0;$x<sizeof($ip_array);$x++){
    echo"
      <tr>
       <td>
        <span>$x</span>
       </td>
       <td>
        <span>$ip_array[$x]</span>
       </td>
      </tr>";
}
echo"
 </tbody>
</table>
";


?>
```

Comment: Why `preg_replace`? I thought you wanted to _collect_ the matched IPs? Right now, you are just replacing them with an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply CBroe. This is what I need help with. I am a bit lost..

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: use `preg_match_all()`, like e.g. [so](https://3v4l.org/d8i3Y)

Comment: what about `ipv6` addresses?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my code after @CBroe's comment. For anyone else dealing with the same problem:

```
<?php


// Find IPs
$fh = fopen("failed_jobs.ibd", "r");
$data = fread($fh, filesize("failed_jobs.ibd"));
fclose($fh); 

$array = explode("\n", $data);
$array_size = sizeof($array);

$ip_array = array();

for($x=0;$x<$array_size;$x++){
    $line = $array[$x];

    if (preg_match('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $line, $ip_match)) {
        $ip = $ip_match[0];

        // Check if IP already exists
        if (!(in_array($ip, $ip_array))) {
            array_push($ip_array, $ip);
        }
    }



}


// Print result
echo"
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <p><b>ID</b></p>
   </th>
   <th>
    <p><b>IP</b></p>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>";
for($x=0;$x<sizeof($ip_array);$x++){
    echo"
      <tr>
       <td>
        <span>$x</span>
       </td>
       <td>
        <span>$ip_array[$x]</span>
       </td>
      </tr>";
}
echo"
 </tbody>
</table>
";


?>
```